# (Java) Priority Queue Lambda Expression

Tags: java

I am studying Java8 by myself. I don't understand a difference between

```java
PriorityQueue<Node> heap = new PriorityQueue<Node>((n1, n2) -> matrix[n2.row][n2.col] - matrix[n1.row][n1.col]);
```

and

```java
PriorityQueue<Node> heap = new PriorityQueue<Node>((n1, n2) -> matrix[n1.row][n1.col] - matrix[n2.row][n2.col]);
```

Let's suppose input and output are below:

```
matrix = [[1,5,9],[10,11,13],[12,13,15]];
k = 8
```

I added a few matrix value using below code:

```java
for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
  if(i < k){
    heap.add(new Node(i, 0));
  }
}
```

```java
class Node{
    int row;
    int col;
    
    public Node(int row, int col) {
        this.row = row;
        this.col = col;
    }
}
```

In this case, 3 different matrix values are added in heap.

1. `PriorityQueue<Node> heap = new PriorityQueue<Node>((n1, n2) -> matrix[n2.row][n2.col] - matrix[n1.row][n1.col])`

> 12, 1, 10

2. `PriorityQueue<Node> heap = new PriorityQueue<Node>((n1, n2) -> matrix[n1.row][n1.col] - matrix[n2.row][n2.col])`

> 1, 10, 12

2nd code shows minimum Heap. Does anyone know the difference between  `matrix[n2.row][n2.col] - matrix[n1.row][n1.col]` and `matrix[n1.row][n1.col] - matrix[n2.row][n2.col]`?

Comment: You have a typo somewhere. The first two code blocks show a difference in order of operands (x-y vs y-x) but elsewhere you're repeating the same version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case the lambda expression is a custom [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) that *compares its two arguments for order, returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second*. Since you can customize it, you can even return a negative number when first argument is numerically greater than the second argument. Assume `matrix[n1.row][n1.col]` is greater than  `matrix[n2.row][n2.col]`, In your first code, the lambda expression will return a possitive number, in the second code, it will return a negative number oppositely.

In PriorityQueue, it always puts samller ones **before** greater ones, in other words, it stores elements in ascending order(for simplicity, assume it's ordered internally). But the order is **decided** by your custom Comparator if you provide one, When you add nodes to PriorityQueue by `heap.add(new Node(i, 0));`, it finally goes to this method:

```
    private void siftUpUsingComparator(int k, E x) {
        while (k > 0) {
            int parent = (k - 1) >>> 1;
            Object e = queue[parent];
            // this is where the custom comparator being used, x is the first argument, 
            // e is the second argument. When it return a positive integer or zero, 
            // x will be positioned after e since comparator says x is greater than e.            
            if (comparator.compare(x, (E) e) >= 0)
                break;
            queue[k] = e;
            k = parent;
        }
        queue[k] = x;
    }
```